# MVC in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to create a sample application (say "hello world!" example) in Model - View - Controller concept using Javascript + HTML 5?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? In its current form, a valid answer would be *"by using a text editor"*. You have to be more specific or better, show us your code and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: **If** you're talking about asp.net. With visual studio and asp.net-mvc installed, you can create a new internet application which will be somewhat of a basic mvc _hello world_ web project.

Comment: Also if you're talking ONLY JS+html then http://knockoutjs.com/ is a nice MVVM library.

Comment: @giddy: I see no indication that the OP is asking about ASP.NET.

Comment: @David sorry misread. Edited comments, Yes it seems like the question is about only MVC in JS but with that one liner question you can never know.

Answer (score 2):

Creating an "application" (even a simple one) is going to take a little more work and is a little more scope than an answer on Stack Overflow can generally provide.

However, if you just want an example of using the MVC pattern in JavaScript then there's [a pretty interesting one here](http://www.alexatnet.com/content/model-view-controller-mvc-javascript).  The example covers just a single HTML element (a `select`) but can be expanded quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.javascriptmvc.com/wiki/index.php?title=Getting_Started